# How can I verify a Bitlocker recovery key?

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

I've recently encrypted my Windows 10 Pro laptop system drive and removable backup drive with Bitlocker.

I've gotten copies of the Recovery keys as text files and stored them in a safe place, as well as backing it up on Microsoft's site via my login account.

However, being a little paranoid (experienced?!), I'd like to verify that the backup keys will actually work when I need them. How can I test/verify that my keys match what the recovery system would want in a real recovery scenario?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also do a quick compare using a powershell command.

1. Open PowerShell as admin
2. Run `manage-bde -protectors -get c:`

Compare the password shown to the key you have saved.

Comment: Perfect - thank you. This is much easier and better than booting into safe mode. I marked this as the correct answer now. That said verifying by actually booting into safe mode seems safe/smart also: "trust but verify"

Comment: It may seem so but this method can be automated. You could check against secret storage and report\update on mismatch.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but I noticed that Windows will prompt for a bitlocker key to reboot into safe mode. So that's where you could test it.